# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '' from SUM() on DATATYPE decimal(10,2)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, double, decimal

Initially encountered  Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '' running this query

`SELECT DATE(Timestamp), COUNT(*), SUM(Amount) FROM remote_tickets WHERE DATE(Timestamp) = '2019-10-31' AND CCTransactionId != '';`

But warning also appears when I issue

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM remote_tickets WHERE CCTransactionId != '';`

BUT **NOT** FOR

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM remote_tickets;`

Schema is

```
CREATE TABLE `remote_tickets` (
  `TicketId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DeviceId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `CustomerCategoryName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `PaymentType` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `CCTransactionId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Timestamp` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How do I track down this issue?  Is it bad data?  Perhaps worth mentioning that I get a warning from mysqlmonitor but not from PHPMyAdmin when issuing `SHOW WARNINGS`.

Comment: Use `DECIMAL(10,2)` for monetary values, not `DOUBLE`.

Comment: @RickJames but I am using DECIMAL(10,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table defines `CCTransactionId` as an integer, but you are comparing it to a string (`''`) in the `WHERE` clause of your query. Hence the warning that you are getting. Accordingly, the query without a `WHERE` clause does not raise the warning.

You probably want:

```
WHERE CCTransactionId IS NOT NULL
```

Or maybe:

```
WHERE CCTransactionId != 0
```